# reinterpret_cast from type 'const char*' to type '__FlashStringHelper*' casts away qualifiers

Tags: c++, avr, avr-studio6

I want to use Adafruit_CC3000 arduino library in AVR Studio. I have followed [this](http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/) Instruction to use Adafruit arduino lib with AVR studio so i can use other AVR function too. But I am getting the same error 50 times while i compile the code.

> Error 5   reinterpret_cast from type 'const char*' to type
>   '__FlashStringHelper*' casts away
>   qualifiers    E:\arduino-1.0.1\libraries\Adafruit_CC3000\Adafruit_CC3000.cpp  183 3   ATmega32_WSClient_CC3K

I have searched on web for such kind of errors. but i failed to understand the issue. I am requesting to make me understand which thing in this code is generatig this error?

Comment: You can't use [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to cast away the `const` qualifier, only [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` can convert between unrelated pointer types, but can't remove `const` or `volatile` qualifiers. You need `const_cast` for that.

Options are (roughly in order of increasing nastiness):

- don't use the wrong pointer type in the first place;
- cast to `const __FlashStringHelper*`, if you don't need to modify the object;
- cast from `char*` if you do need to modify it;
- use `reinterpret_cast<__FlashStringHelper*>(const_cast<char*>(whatever))` or the brute-force `(__FlashStringHelper*)whatever` if you insist on abandoning the type system entirely.